# zend-form select optgroup, how to specify id

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Hello i am using *Zend Framework Form* and have tried to get this example to work http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8252, but it fails xD

this is my code

```
$options = Array
(
    [] => Qualsiasi Agente
    [agenti_attivi] => Array
        (
            [4] => Giovanni Abc
            [10] => Luigi Abc
            [13] => Michela Abc
        )

);

$agenti->addMultiOptions($options);
```

and the generated code is :

```
<select name="agente_id" id="agente_id" tabindex="6">
    <option value="" label="Qualsiasi Agente" selected="selected">Qualsiasi Agente</option>
    <optgroup id="agente_id-optgroup-Agenti attivi: " label="Agenti attivi: ">
    <option value="4" label="Giovanni Abc">Giovanni Abc</option>
    <option value="10" label="Luigi Capoarea">Luigi Abc</option>
    <option value="13" label="Michela Abc">Michela Abc</option>
    </optgroup>

</select>
```

where **id="agente_id-optgroup-Agenti attivi: "**  is not xhtml valid *Line 724, Column 44: value of attribute "id" must be a single token*

i am using zend 1.11.10

thanks

Comment: Actually, there seems to be an unresolved bug report in ZF about this: See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11540

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom view helper FormSelect that extends the core FormSelect and then  modify the code.

1. Include the path to your view helpers in the bootstrap file

```
protected function _initHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addHelperPath('My/View/Helper', 'My_View_Helper');
}
```

1. The custom view helper. It's a copy of Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect but with small modification.

   class My_View_Helper_FormSelect extends Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect
   {

   ```
   public function formSelect($name, $value = null, $attribs = null,
       $options = null, $listsep = "<br />\n")
   {
       $info = $this->_getInfo($name, $value, $attribs, $options, $listsep);
       extract($info); // name, id, value, attribs, options, listsep, disable

       // force $value to array so we can compare multiple values to multiple
       // options; also ensure it's a string for comparison purposes.
       $value = array_map('strval', (array) $value);

       // check if element may have multiple values
       $multiple = '';

       if (substr($name, -2) == '[]') {
           // multiple implied by the name
           $multiple = ' multiple="multiple"';
       }

       if (isset($attribs['multiple'])) {
           // Attribute set
           if ($attribs['multiple']) {
               // True attribute; set multiple attribute
               $multiple = ' multiple="multiple"';

               // Make sure name indicates multiple values are allowed
               if (!empty($multiple) && (substr($name, -2) != '[]')) {
                   $name .= '[]';
               }
           } else {
               // False attribute; ensure attribute not set
               $multiple = '';
           }
           unset($attribs['multiple']);
       }

       // now start building the XHTML.
       $disabled = '';
       if (true === $disable) {
           $disabled = ' disabled="disabled"';
       }

       // Build the surrounding select element first.
       $xhtml = '<select'
               . ' name="' . $this->view->escape($name) . '"'
               . ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"'
               . $multiple
               . $disabled
               . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
               . ">\n    ";

       // build the list of options
       $list       = array();
       $translator = $this->getTranslator();
       foreach ((array) $options as $opt_value => $opt_label) {
           if (is_array($opt_label)) {
               $opt_disable = '';
               if (is_array($disable) && in_array($opt_value, $disable)) {
                   $opt_disable = ' disabled="disabled"';
               }
               if (null !== $translator) {
                   $opt_value = $translator->translate($opt_value);
               }
               $opt_id = ' id="' . $this->formatElementId($id . '-optgroup-' . $opt_value) . '"';
               $list[] = '<optgroup'
                       . $opt_disable
                       . $opt_id
                       . ' label="' . $this->view->escape($opt_value) .'">';
               foreach ($opt_label as $val => $lab) {
                   $list[] = $this->_build($val, $lab, $value, $disable);
               }
               $list[] = '</optgroup>';
           } else {
               $list[] = $this->_build($opt_value, $opt_label, $value, $disable);
           }
       }

       // add the options to the xhtml and close the select
       $xhtml .= implode("\n    ", $list) . "\n</select>";

       return $xhtml;
   }

   private function formatElementId($id)
   {
       // in here put whatever filter you want for the id value
       $id = trim(strtr($id, array('[' => '-', ']' => '', ' ' => '', ':' => '')), '-');
       $id = strtolower($id);
       return $id;
   }
   ```

   }

Done. Create multi select element with a valid id.

```
<?php
$this->addElement('multiSelect', 'agente_id', array(
    'label' => 'Label Name:',
    'multiOptions' => array(
        '' => 'Qualsiasi Agente',
        'Agenti attivi: ' => array(
            4 => 'Giovanni Verdi',
            10 => 'Luigi Capoarea',
            13 => 'Michela Passarin',
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: Yes, I also think it's the best possible workaround. Anyway, I think ZF should filter the optgroup label before just injecting it into the ID. Should it be considered a bug in the framework?

Answer (score 2):

try this, it's works for me:

```
$select = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('select');
$options = Array(
    '' => 'Qualsiasi Agente',
    'agenti_attivi' => Array(
            4 => 'Giovanni Verdi',
            10 => 'Luigi Capoarea',
            13 => 'Michela Passarin'
        )
);
$this->addElements(array($xxxx,$select,$yyyy)); // $this : the form instance
```

and the result is:

```
<select id="select" name="select">
  <option label="Qualsiasi Agente" value="">Qualsiasi Agente</option>
  <optgroup label="agenti_attivi">
    <option label="Giovanni Verdi" value="4">Giovanni Verdi</option>
    <option label="Luigi Capoarea" value="10">Luigi Capoarea</option>
    <option label="Michela Passarin" value="13">Michela Passarin</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

the problem is that the id attribute does not accept spaces and special special characters:

```
id="agente_id-optgroup-Agenti attivi: "
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend is usually pretty good about rendering the proper html, given a doctype.

Try setting your doctype like this if you aren't already.

```
<?php
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
$viewRenderer->initView();
$viewRenderer->view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
```

AND

```
<?php echo $this->doctype(); ?>
```

at the top of your layout

I don't have a install of ZF i can mess with easy, if this doesn't work ill setup a test environment.

Comment: Thats too bad. In that case, I would write a custom View Helper / Zend_Form_Element to handle this. (i believe that is the gist of the patch in your link)